# Add data to DbContext only once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit, xunit.net

I created a XUnit fixture to define an EF Core context initial data:

```
public class ServiceProviderFixture : IDisposable {

  public IServiceProvider Provider { get; private set; }

  public ServiceProviderFixture() {
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddDbContext<Context>(x => { x.UseInMemoryDatabase("Database"); });
    Provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    BuildContext();
  }

  private void BuildContext() { 
    Context context = Provider.GetService<Context>();
    context.Countries.Add(new Country { Code = "fr", Name = "France" });
    context.SaveChanges();
  }

  public void Dispose() { } 

}
```

Then on a few tests I use it as follows:

```
 public class TestMethod1 : IClassFixture<ServiceProviderFixture> {

   public Test(ServiceProviderFixture fixture) {
    _fixture = fixture;
   } 

  [Fact]
  public async Task Test1() {

    IServiceProvider provider = _fixture.Provider;

    Context context = provider.GetService<Context>();

    // Add test data to context
    // Test some method

  }

}
```

When I run one test it goes well ... But when I use `dotnet test` to run all tests I get:

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: fr
The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data:
ServiceProviderFixture fixture)
```

I believe that BuildContext() is being called one time per TestClass on the same context.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you always name your in-memory database the same way, you always get the same database again.

You have to name it differently for each test case (e. g. `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`).

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(x => 
    x.UseInMemoryDatabase($"Database{Guid.NewGuid()}")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check in your BuildContext if there is any data, if not create it otherwise just do nothing. Or you can just clean created data after the test is completed.

```
  private void BuildContext() { 
    Context context = Provider.GetService<Context>();
    if(!context.Countries.Any())
    {
        context.Countries.Add(new Country { Code = "fr", Name = "France" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
```